# PHP versions are shown out of order

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation, documentation-versions

In my flurry of version edits yesterday in documentation, I noticed that in PHP's documentation editor, version 4.4 is shown as between 5.0 and 5.1. I checked and there aren't any invisible characters in that entry. What caused this?

[Example of such behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/504/classes-and-objects)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue here is that documentation is ordering versions by release date, and not by the ordering of the versions table.

See https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/189/introduction#t=201609201503255693812&a=versions: 4.4 has been released after 5.0, thus the implicit order is 4.3, 5.0, 4.4, 5.1, ...

Thus, it's not a bug, but by design. The design is questionable though...

Comment: That's certainly a strange set of (apparently correct) release dates.

Comment: @RamenChef Not nearly as strange as the release history for PHP 6... (search Google for it, if you're not familiar).

Comment: @RamenChef It's not that unlikely to have another minor release if there are _small_ needed BC breaks for extended support of a major version branch. (I mean PHP is not following semver, but micro versions **MUST** be ABI compatible.)

Comment: @EdCottrell What's so strange about that? ES4 seems to have the same kind of history - there are no releases at all.

Comment: @Bergi That was supposed to be a joke. The PHP 6 release history is "strange" in the sense that it doesn't exist, at least not in any formal releases, despite the years of talk. Obviously, that happens sometimes. That doesn't mean it's not unusual.

Answer (score 1):

I've just [edited the order of PHP versions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/189/getting-started-with-php) and split them into multiple groups. Hopefully this will make versioning clearer.